# Twig add attribute with value in a variable

Tags: drupal, twig, drupal-views, drupal-8

**Using Drupal 8**

I want to print out a field's content into the `src` attribute. I have the following template for my view:

```
<div class="videoWrapperHD">
     <iframe width="560" height="315" src="{{ rows[0].content | raw }}" 
      frameborder="0" allowfullscreen>
     </iframe>
</div>
```

But the iframe gets filled with my own site's "*Page Not Found*" page instead of the Youtube Video because Twig prints out a whole lot of debug comments before and after printing the variable `rows[0].content`.

Is it possible to disable the debug comments for a specific field? I don't want to have to be disabling/enabling debug to make sure it works as expected.

I also tried using `{{ attributes.setAttribute('src', {{ rows[0].content }} ) }}` , but no dice.

Another failed attempt was:

```
{% set iframe_src = rows[0].content %}
<div class="videoWrapperHD">
    <iframe width="560" height="315" {{ attributes.setAttribute('src', iframe_src) }}
     frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

My last idea was this:

```
{% set url = rows[0].content | raw %}
{% set iframe_src = 'src=' ~ url %}

<div class="videoWrapperHD">
   <iframe {{ iframe_src }} ></iframe>
</div>
```

But it prints out **src=Array**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is in [another question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/202885/get-views-field-value-in-twig-template), I'm pasting it here in case that one gets deleted. The author of the following answer is [@4k4](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/47547/4k4)

`field.content` is the rendered field. And in views that means it is no longer a render array, but the finally rendered markup. So this is very problematic to use it as a class name, not only because of twig debug.

Better use the row data, where you find the entity object with the field data from the database. Use clean_class to escape it for using it as a class name:

```
{{ row._entity.field_myfield.value|clean_class }}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

in your .theme

```
function your_theme_preprocess_field(&$variables, $hook) {
    switch ($variables['element']['#field_name']) {
        case 'field_iframe_src':
            $variables['iframe_src'] = $variables['items'][0]['content']['#context']['value'];
            break;
    }
}
```

in your twig

```
   <iframe width="560" height="315" src="{{ iframe_src|raw}}" 
      frameborder="0" allowfullscreen>
     </iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like something that would have to be done in the preprocessor. If you grab it from the node object, instead of the content array it shouldn't get all that debug nonsense.

You should also make sure that your URL isn't doing something evil... if you only expect youtube videos you should do some checking to make sure that that is what you get from the content.

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21node%21node.module/function/template_preprocess_node/8.2.x

See $node, find the value, sanitize/double check it's value, then set it to $variables['variable_name'] and you should be able to use it in twig with {{variable_name}}